# Ansible - Read file in remote server and use the output to replace a line in configuration file

Tags: ansible

Under /etc/osci we store a single line string for our monitoring name. 
I created a ansible playbook that copy-s the default zabbix configuration to the remote server and now I want to use the ansible replace module to replace a string in the newly copied configuration file with the output of /etc/osci

In salt I can execute a cmd.shell that runs in the remote server and reads the file output to a variable(using cat), but I'm having trouble using the same method with Ansible.

What's the correct way to do this?

```
- shell: cat /etc/osci
  register: data
```

This does not work, calling out the data variable in system returns 0 output. Is there another way in doing this? I don't really want to use fetch to download the file to local host and read using lookup.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are probably using the wrong [return value](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html#return-values) of the register command. Adding `.stdout` should return the content of the file. Use it like this:

```
- name: Get osci content.
  shell: cat /etc/osci
  register: data

- debug:
    msg: "{{ data.stdout }}"
```

Comment: That worked well. Now the only thing I need to figure out is how to remove the '"' symbols around the output and I should be golden